What is the Git command to sync an already deployed github project with the visual studio code?
I  have my project in visual studio code and I have published in github as well. But due to some faulty , my node modules got published as well in github. After performing rm -rf node modules apparently the node modules also got removed from my project in vs code so i can't committ any further updates from vs code to github. it shows error

Empty commits cannot be created

So how do i sync my project again with the one published in github? The project already has a live hyperlink and deployed through vercel and I can't change since it has been shared with many other people.
I tried adding the origin again by git remote add originbut it didn't work as it shows error remote origin already exists.

Try to clone the repository from GitHub by git clone <URL>

Will this override the existing one and sync with original or create the project again?

not override exactly, it will be a separate set of folders on your operating system. It'll just be another copy that will be in accordance with your origin. Just make sure this new set of folders don't coincide with the existing one, like don't have .git of your previous project with the new clone. Hope that makes sense XD
